# 最新のgoogle-api-objectivec-clientをCocoapodsでインストール

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

下記にあるgoogle-api-objectivec-clientをCocoapodsでインストールしたいのですが、
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Cocoapodsでは1.0.422（Rev422）がインストールされます。
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Google-API-Client

これを現在では最新のRev446をインストールする方法を探しております。

githubでは:headをつければ最新のコミットになる認識ですが、
svnだと方法が見つからず困っております。

```
Podfile
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios , '7.1'
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'google-api-objectivec-client', :head
```

環境
xcode6.3
cocoapods 0.37.2

Answer (score 1):

自分で最新のリビジョンを参照するPodspecを書いて、それを使ってインストールするのが簡単だと思います。

下はおそらく最低限インストールできるであろうPodspecです。上のリンク先を見たところ、オリジナルのPodspecはもっとたくさんの記述がありましたので、おそらくもっと書く必要があると思います。

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "Google-API-Client"
  s.version      = "1.0.446"
  s.ios.deployment_target = "5.0"

  s.source       = { svn: 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/', revision: '446' }
  s.dependency 'gtm-http-fetcher', '~> 1.0.141'
  s.dependency 'gtm-oauth2', '~> 1.0.125'

  s.requires_arc = false
end
```

これをPodfileのほうからは次のような形で使用します。

```
pod 'Google-API-Client', :podspec => './Google-API-Client.podspec'
```

これは`Podfile`と`Google-API-Client.podspec`が同じディレクトリにある、という例です。Gistなどを使って管理するひともいますし、`source`指定でカスタムのSpecリポジトリを指定できるのでそれを使うのもいいと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧な解説ありがとうございます！
Podspecを作ってみます。

追伸
前に何かの勉強会で登壇されてたのをお見かけしました。
有名人にお会いした気分で嬉しいです！